# Xamarin c# android: change color text in a substring?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, colors, substring

I need to highlight some words in a string with different colors. The string will then be assigned to the Text property of a TextView. I did not find a simple and effective method to do this. Can you help me? Thank you . Maddox

Answer (score 2):

```
textview.SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor("#787887"));
string character="Helloworld Developer";
string withoutspecialcharacter="Helloworld";
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(character);
spannable.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), character.IndexOf(withoutspecialcharacter), (character.IndexOf(withoutspecialcharacter)) + (withoutspecialcharacter.Length), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);

textview.TextFormatted = spannable ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with the help of **SpannableString**.

Please Look at SpannableString in **Xamarin Document** [SpannableString](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Text.SpannableString/)

Please Look at SpannableString in **Android Document**
[SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)

**Example**

```
var textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.my_label);
var span = new SpannableString("My Label");

span.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Red), 0, 2, 0);  // "My" is red
span.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.Blue), 3, 8, 0); // "Label" is blue
textView.SetText(span, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert HTML tags to a spannable:

```
ISpanned html;
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
    html = Html.FromHtml("<font color='red'> StackOverflow </font>", FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy);
else
    // Obsolete in N+
    html = Html.FromHtml("<font color='blue'> StackOverflow </font>");
textview.SetText(html, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
```